# Automatically resize rChart in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts

How can I automatically resize an rChart plot in shiny? I would like to fit the plot to the screen of the user, like it is done for regular plots with renderPlot. Here's a minimal example:

```
#Server.R
require(rCharts)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$chart1 <- renderChart2({
    r1 <- rPlot(mpg ~ wt | am + vs, data = mtcars, type = "point", color = "gear")
    return(r1)
    })
  })


#ui.R.
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')
shinyUI(shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("title panel"),      
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("sidebar panel"),
        mainPanel("main panel",
                   chartOutput("chart1", 'polycharts'))
      )
    )
 ))
```

I tried adding:

```
w <- session$clientData$output_chart1_width
r1$set(width = w)
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Dynamic resizing is not available in rCharts yet. You will need some hacks to achieve it currently.

Comment: Thanks, could you reveal these hacks?

Comment: Let me try to get you an example.

Comment: +1 .. have exactly the same question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there: rChart's `chartOutput` doesn't pass its size, so the workaround is to use a `plotOutput` object to do this.

Here is a solution that works for me:

```
#server.R
require(rCharts)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart1 <- renderChart2({
    r1 <- rPlot(mpg ~ wt | am + vs, data = mtcars, type = "point", color = "gear")
    r1$set(width = session$clientData$output_plot1_width)
    return(r1)
  })
})


#ui.R
require(rCharts)
options(RCHART_LIB = 'polycharts')
shinyUI(shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title panel"),      
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel"),
    mainPanel("main panel",
              plotOutput("plot1", height = "1px"),
              chartOutput("chart1", 'polycharts')
              )
  )
)
))
```

Note: here is another example I wrote with a nvd3 type chart: https://gist.github.com/nassimhaddad/3057e9ac687591fa5138

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work inside a `tabsetPanel` but when I add it to both `tabPanel`s my plots disappear.  It works when I add it to just one for that specific tab... any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `highcharts` and adding HTML code just after the `showOutput` function worked for me.

```
#ui.R.
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("title panel"),      
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("sidebar panel"),
        mainPanel("main panel",
                   showOutput("chart1", 'highcharts'),
                   HTML('<style>.rChart {width: 100%; height: 600px}</style>'))
      )
    )
 ))
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It has worked for me but is still buggy... when I re-size my window and then click on a different tab my plot is squished to almost nothing... until I re-size again with that plot displayed.